# PyQt4 cannot import QtGui but can import QtCore

Tags: pyqt4, python-3.3, qtgui

I installed python3.3 x86 (official python.org installer) on this windows 7 32-bit

then installed PyQt4-4.10 for python3.3 windows x86 from here [PyQt4-4.10-gpl-Py3.3-Qt5.0.1-x32-2.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.10/PyQt4-4.10-gpl-Py3.3-Qt5.0.1-x32-2.exe/download), an official installer too, a full PyQt4 installation (including Qt Runtime)

I double checked that both python and PyQt4 are on $PATH

but it seems I can import some packages(eg, QtCore) but not others (eg, QtGui)

although they are side by side in the same path

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> QtCore.__file__
'C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt4\\QtCore.pyd'
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.exists('C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt4\\QtGui.pyd')
True
>>> from PyQt4 import Qt
>>> from PyQt4 import QtXml
>>> from PyQt4 import QtNetwork
>>> from PyQt4 import QtDesigner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtDesigner
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>> os.path.exists('C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt4\\QtDesigner.pyd')
True
```

Comment: works for QtCore.pyd fails for both QtGui.pyd and Qt5Gui.dll and produces this message:
"OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found"
although both files are in the same path of QtCore.pyd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qt5Gui.dll depends on D3dCOMPILER_43.dll, which is part of DirectX. You can update your installation with the [DirectX End-User Runtime Web Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35).

Comment: Thank you very much, that sorted out the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like to install the whole DirectX you can do the following:

First download the Directx redistributable: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109 (this is a kind of self extracting MS-Cabinet-file)

Then in Linux for example (Debian based - should work similar on other distros):

```
sudo apt-get install cabextract
mkdir cabs
cabextract -d cabs -F JUN2010\* directx_Jun2010_redist.exe
cd cabs
mkdir x64
cabextract -d x64 -F \*.dll *_x64.cab
```

In Windows you can extract cab-files for example with Winrar. Some windows versions included a command line utility for cab-files - I think it was called `extract`.